# IIS 8.0 Detailed Error - 405.0 - Method Not Allowed

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I am just looking for the different causes that might cause this error.  I was working on an intranet site and nothing up to that point had gone wrong.  I was working on using Blueimp's Fileupload plugin and I was able to upload files to my server no problem.  I am using a WebAPI controller in my MVC 4 application to handle the upload of the file

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Upload()
```

All of a sudden, in one of my test runs, I got this error and haven't been able to get rid of it.  I have tried removing WebADV (not even installed in my machine) etc...I am running out of options here and I cannot trace back this error.

Any help whatsoever will be appreciated, even if it's pointing to another post.  I apologize for the vagueness of the post, but I cannot seem to be able to trace my error and thus, I'm a little desperate.

Once again, thanks!

Config:

```
<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12807331/#comment23576850_13620659, perhaps? Or, can you share the `<system.webServer>` config? Also, which HTTP Verb is `Upload()` associated with? Does your API route include an `{action}` placeholder? And, does the plugin send requests to [`/api/controller/upload` or just `/api/controller`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10917370)? Are the requests [cross-origin](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10980767) (ref: [same-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript))?

Comment: I will post my <system.webServer> config in an edit.  Upload is associated with HttpGet and HttpPost (yes, both) and the request goes to api/upload (/api/controller in the RouteConfig file)

Comment: I instantiate a repository in public UploadController(), but that never fires (and thus it's commented out, I have set breakpoints when it was working)...I used to think it was a problem, something overwritten in my settings file, but you seem to think the problem lies with my WebAPI controller?  It's weird since this works in my collegue's computers, except for mine.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not trying to say that's the problem. I'm just info fishing. Your question doesn't have a lot of technical details.

Comment: I do apologize about that...I know it's very vague but it's because I really don't know where to start.  You are being of great help btw :) Thanks for taking the time, I posted the config section

Comment: For some reason adding them doesn't do anything.  I really appreciate your help man :) I will keep looking and trying of course!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue in the following manner. I downloaded Ninject.WebApi.DependencyResolver.  This allowed me to register WebApi with my controller factory.  After that, changing the path (eg "api/upload" (api/controllername)) to "api/upload/upload" fixed the issue!